# MySQL is cancelling request after first entry is mismatch

Tags: mariadb

So i have written a little program that's supposed to get certain information from a database i'm hosting on my computer via XAMPP.

The request inside the program looks like this:

```
SELECT priority, platform FROM jobs WHERE priority = (SELECT MAX(priority) WHERE `platform` != '<the platform needed>')
```

If for example i give it "linux" as platform, it's supposed to give me the result(s) where the platform is anything but linux and priority is highest. That itself works fine as long as 'platform' isn't linux in the first entry of that table. However if it is linux, the Database just returns nothing (no errors, it just sees the job as completed)

So for example he have this Table:

```
linux 0
windows 0
windows 1
```

If i give it the instruction

```
SELECT priority, platform 
FROM jobs 
WHERE priority = (SELECT MAX(priority) 
                  WHERE `platform` != 'windows')
```

it returns (linux, 0) because that's the only entry that matches all conditions.

But if i give it the instruction

```
SELECT priority, platform 
FROM jobs 
WHERE priority = (SELECT MAX(priority) 
                  WHERE `platform` != 'linux')
```

it returns nothing because the first row would be a mismatch in this case. (Confirmed this theory through playing around with the order and priority of the entries)

It's the same if i give those instructions directly via the SQL panel so i don't think it has anything to do with the program itself.

This is the Code inside the program handling the request:

```
db = con.con(host, user, password, database, port)
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = 'SELECT priority, platform FROM jobs WHERE priority = (SELECT MAX(priority) WHERE `platform` ! '<the platform needed>')'

try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in result:
        priority = row[0]
        platform = row[1]
        # redirect to another script

except:
    return False
```

Anyone got any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot reproduce the behaviour you describe! The logic of your query is incorrect (you need to filter out the unwanted platform in the outer query as well), but mysql is not going to cancel a query just because the first row it encounters do not match a criteria. Please bear in mind that sql tables do not have an inherent order, the only way to force an order of a resultset is by providing the order by clause.

Comment: Why would i need to filter it out twice when i already gave it the instructions to only pick the hightest priority from those entries that match the platform i need?

Comment: ??? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6417ec7de06f6ce081a11480a3bd04ff

Comment: Are you sure you aren't using MARIADB rather than mysql? I can reproduce the behavior you are seeing using @Akina fiddle if I change the server to mariadb. SELECT VERSION() to verify.

Comment: Try `SELECT MAX(priority) "priority", platform
FROM jobs 
WHERE NOT platform = 'windows'
GROUP BY platform`

Comment: @P.Salmon well i guess that was my fault rather than the databse... Didn't know XAMPP was using MariaDB. Thanks

Also how would i achieve what i want in maria?

Comment: @Titus By fact your query is very strange. The subquery used in WHERE have no FROM clause... not tell me, where the values for columns mentioned in this (correlated!) subquery are taken from? And see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&rdbms2=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=a718ad560113260b4679143433bc92ca

Comment: @Akina Well, I tried it with FROM because i thought maybe that would fix that but the opposite was the case, i got an even worse result. But i have to admit it is kinda scraped from the little things i know about databases + some research + some own "bug fixes" so i was kinda expecting some issues. Also thanks for your Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mariadb use from in sub query and test platform in main query

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
create table t
(platform varchar(20), priority int);
insert into t values
('linux' ,0),
('freebsd' ,0),
('freedos' ,1),
('windows', 0),
('windows' ,1);

SELECT priority, platform 
FROM t
WHERE priority = (SELECT MAX(priority) from t
                  WHERE `platform` != 'windows')
      and platform <> 'windows'
;


+----------+----------+
| priority | platform |
+----------+----------+
|        1 | freedos  |
+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

SELECT priority, platform 
FROM t 
WHERE priority = (SELECT MAX(priority) from t
                  WHERE `platform` != 'linux')
      and platform <> 'linux'
;

+----------+----------+
| priority | platform |
+----------+----------+
|        1 | freedos  |
|        1 | windows  |
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the job